# onClick not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes' error in TypeScript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tsx

I have this code for a component:

**Feedback.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Feedback.css';

import FeedbackButton from './FeedbackButton';

function Feedback() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState<boolean>(false)

  return (
    <div className="Feedback">
      <FeedbackButton onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Feedback;
```

The `FeedbackButton` component looks like this:

**FeedbackButton.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import feedbackicon from './feedback.svg';
import './Feedback.css';

function FeedbackButton() {
  return (
    <button className="Feedback-button" type="button">
      <img src={feedbackicon} className="Feedback-button-icon" alt="feedback" />
    </button>
  );
}

export default FeedbackButton;
```

On the line `<FeedbackButton onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} />` I get the error `Type '{ onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.`

I searched it up and tried to fix it using FunctionalComponent, but I got the same error. How can I make this onClick with useState work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
function FeedbackButton(props:{onClick:()=>void}) {
  return (
    <button className="Feedback-button" type="button" onClick={props.onClick}>
      <img src={feedbackicon} className="Feedback-button-icon" alt="feedback" />
    </button>
  );
}
```

something like this should work for you even better you can copy the type from button onclick to your props and have better typing if needed

Comment: Perfect thank you. Is this a good and clean way to handle this, or is there, in your opinion, a more best practise way of handling such things

Comment: when i have components in my project, i try to keep the props small, usually create an interface called `Props`, unless you are creating a library that can be used in many different ways, that case you'll probably extend your Props interface from the Button Props, which looks like this `React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>`. when you extend from button props, you also need to pass those props down to button as well. you can find more info about the props in react typings, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

@tonakai fixes the problem well!

However, very often, the `onClick` logic is "owned" by the parent, and it is more natural to not have the child "know" anything about clicks that the parent is managing.

For example, when you have a child component which is implemented in multiple places, and only some places require the `onClick`.

So I sometimes wrap it like

```
<div onClick=...>
  <CustomComponent></CustomComponent>
</div>
```

This has the disadvantage of adding an extra div in the DOM, but can be worth it for component de-coupling.